# UDP using socket API

Tags: api, vb6, sockets, udp

My server use UDP. It sends 900bytes/1ms to my program automatically after being acquired. I'm using socket API in Windows (VB6). I had made a test and I know that the message processing time (about 0.3ms) of my program is shorter than cycle time (1ms). So the cause should be socket internal buffer. I try calling `setsockopt` function to set the bigger buffer:

```
setsockopt(SockNum, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, SockBuffer(1), 1048576)
```

but I still lost data. How can I fix my problem?
I'm using `recv` function to receive data. Should `recvfrom` be better?

Futhermore, I need make a FIFO buffer for UDP. How I can do so (i.e. algorithms or examples)?

Answer (score 2):

In your question you seem to be complaining about using UDP and losing data.

If you are using UDP, you are going to lose data. The way that you avoid losing data is to use TCP, not UDP.  If you try to take the User Datagram Protocol and add reliable delivery of data to it, you will end up with something that has all of the flow-control and data windowing of TCP... except it won't be implemented as well as you want.

Remember, "Those who do not understand TCP are doomed to reinvent it....  poorly"

Comment: you can always implement a TCP like SYN/ACK system, but with less verifications, thus being a middle ground between TCP and UDP. But if the problem is losing data, it's probably because of UDP, yes.

Comment: thanks, but my server is a electronic board. It use UDP and I can't change

Comment: regarding, my computer (running my program - client) connect direct to the server by 5m cable so I think it is hardly to lost data.

Comment: There are many places to lose data other than the physical layer. They might be lost because of background processes on your computer, or buffers being overflowed, or what have you. 

As soon as you add SYN/ACK, you are re-inventing TCP. But badly. What about your flow control? Window size? Sliding window sizes? Etc.